# Program doesn't terminate when reaching the end of the main method

Tags: java, joptionpane

I have a program where I ask for an input from the user before I launch it.

```
public static void main(String args[]) 
{
    String database = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(new JFrame(), "Enter a DB:");
    if(database!=null && database.foundInDB()) {
        SPVerification spv = new SPVerification();
        spv.setVisible(true);
    }
    //System.exit(1);  Without it the program doesn't terminate although it's the end
    //                 of the main function.                  
}
```

If the user enters a database that's not found, the program shouldn't be executed.

When I enter a wrong DB name, the code below `if` statement doesn't execute, so I reach the end of the main method, but the program doesn't terminate, but if I add `system.exit(1)` after the `if` statement, the program terminates. Why do I need to call `System.exit(1)` although I've reached the end of main?

Comment: It seems that theres running a thread in background, which blocks the application.
Do you run any threads elsewhere in the application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have created a new `JFrame` which, by default, will not close as there is nothing to trigger the window to be disposed such as a `WindowEvent`. As this appears to be a non-UI based application, you could simply use:

```
JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter a DB:");
```

Comment: Yes.. I just changed it and it worked. I missed that `new JFrame()`.. Effect of too much hours of working

Answer (score 6):

You're showing a Swing dialog, which starts up the event dispatch thread. This is a non-daemon thread, so will prevent the program from exiting.

For a normal Swing application, this is exactly what you want: all `main()` should do is gather any configuration information and create the main frame.

One solution to your problem is to wrap the dialog code in a call to [SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeAndWait%28java.lang.Runnable%29).

Answer (score 3):

```
JFrame jframe = new JFrame()
String answer = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(jframe, "Enter a DB:")
System.err.println(answer)
jframe.dispose()
```

Answer (score 0):

You might call `.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);` on your JFrame so that the JVM terminates after closing the JFrame (given the fact all other running threads are daemons).