# Java program not closing

Tags: java, swing, jframe

When I try to use:

```
JFrame jk = new JFrame();
jk.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
String s = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(jk, "PassWord:", "Introduzir PassWord",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```

My java program just dont close. But if I use just this:

```
String s = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "PassWord:", "Introduzir PassWord",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```

It closes no problem. Any ideas why? (can post all my code if necessary)

Comment: We do not need ***all*** your code, please think of [MCVE].

Comment: See [Program doesn't terminate when reaching the end of the main method](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15549887). It may also be worth reading non-accepted answers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15549957 which provides more detailed explanation and https://stackoverflow.com/a/15550147 which gives alternative solution.

Answer (score -1):

Add following line to your code where you are creating the GUI

```
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

it will tell Swing how to properly behave when you close your application.

Comment: Minor comment, but I believe `DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE` is generally preferred (in case there are multiple `JFrame`s being displayed).

Comment: Application still will not close since user can't close JFrame which was not shown tho him.